# How to find slowest GET/POST request in Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, profiling

I am working on application which uses **Laravel** **framework**. Yesterday my manager came and told me find top 10 slowest GET/POST request in entire application. So is there any tool available for this which will record time of each request and give me benchmark data ?

Comment: you can try `telescope`

Comment: I think you will have to use some monitoring service, local like Telescope but on steroid like Telescope with Enlightn https://www.laravel-enlightn.com/ or external saas like Blackfire.io, New Relic or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few solutions for this "issue".

You can use Telescope, Clockwork or an external service like Blackfire.

If this is a one time thing, then a setup like Blackfire or Telescope might not be worth it as you can implement a timing monitor yourself quite easily using a middleware like the following (untested):

```php
class TimerMiddleware
{
    
    public function handle(Request $request, $next)
    {
        // Use the internally stored request start timestamp or fallback to
        // microtime if it isn't available
        $time_start = $request->server('REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT', microtime(true));
        
        // Run the rest of the pipeline
        $response = $next($request);
        
        // Calculate the time spent on the request
        $time_elapsed = microtime(true) - $time_start;
        
        // Fetch and log the entry for the request if possible
        // Only skips if there's no route available for the request (just in case)
        if ($log_entry = $this->getLogEntry($request, $response, $time_elapsed)) {
            \Log::channel('request-timing')->debug($log_entry);
        }
        
        return $response;
    }
    
    private function getLogEntry(Request $request, $response, $time) : ?string
    {
        $route = $request->route();
        
        // Guard clause in case there's no route for the request
        if (!$route) {
            return null;
        }
        
        // If the response is an actual response object, then fetch the response
        // code from that, otherwise we'll just assume a 200 reaponse.
        $response_code = $response instanceof Response
            ? $response->getStatusCode()
            : 200;
        
        // Basic request info
        $method = $request->method();
        $uri = $route->uri();
        
        // If you don't have multiple domains then you can just omit the domain
        $domain = $route->domain();
    
        // Time with ms precision should be enough
        $time = round($time, 3);
        
        return "{$method} - {$response_code} - {$domain} - {$uri} - {$time}";
    }
}
```

Add a logging channel to `config/logging.php` like so:

Note: If your application is running on Kubernetes or similar setup, then you'd have to store the logs somewhere else.

```php
    'channels' => [
        ...
        'request-timing' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/request-timing.log'),
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL_SINGLE', 'debug'),
        ],
        ...
    ]
```

Add the middleware to the global middleware stack in `App\Http\Kernel`:

```php
    protected $middleware = [
        ...
        TimerMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

---

I've used the above approach before, and it does the job - It's not fancy, pretty or possibly the best solution, but if you're only doing this once, then you'd be able to deploy the above, let it run for a few days, pull the logs, analyze the logs and get the results you're looking for.